# Get multiple value onchange from multiple input Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onchange, multiple-value, clonenode

[image]

I'm trying to get every value from the charge field according to type payment. When both price and pay have a value, the charge input field will be **filled by pay - price**, and the total amount field will be filled when the type payment option was chosen.

[image]

In the second situation, when I have more than one form and the same type of payment (for example CASH), it will automatically sum for both charges and display TOTAL AMOUNT DUE CASH.

And this is what I've done

```js
// extend form
const btn = document.getElementById("add-button");
const formClone = document.querySelector(".clone");
const parentForm = document.querySelector(".wrappers");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const clone = formClone.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((e) => {
    e.value = "";
  });
  parentForm.appendChild(clone);

  const deleteForm = document.createElement("button");
  deleteForm.innerText = "X";
  deleteForm.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "btn-sm");
  clone.appendChild(deleteForm);

  deleteForm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  });
});

const payment = document.querySelector(".type-payment");
const price = document.querySelector(".input-price");
const pay = document.querySelector(".input-pay");
const allInputSum = document.querySelectorAll(".sum");
const inputTotal = document.querySelector(".input-total");

let result;
let totalValue;
function handleSelectChange(event) {
  result = payment.value;
  totalValue = pay.value - price.value;
  inputTotal.value = totalValue.toLocaleString();

  let inputSum = Array.from(allInputSum).filter((e) => {
    if (e.id == result) {
      e.value = inputTotal.value;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="add-button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add Form</button>
<div class="wrappers">
  <div class="row clone mb-2">
    <div class="col px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control rounded-0 input-price"
          placeholder="Price"
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control rounded-0 input-pay"
          placeholder="Pay"
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <select
          class="form-control rounded-0 type-payment"
          role="button"
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
        >
          <option value="CASH">CASH</option>
          <option value="DEBIT">DEBIT</option>
          <option value="CASHLESS">CASHLESS</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
          value="0.00"
          type="text"
          class="form-control rounded-0 input-total"
          disabled
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pr-0">
      <input
        class="form-control total rounded-0"
        disabled
        placeholder="TOTAL CASH"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
      <input
        id="CASH"
        class="form-control rounded-0 sum"
        disabled
        placeholder="0.00"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pr-0">
      <input
        class="form-control total rounded-0"
        disabled
        placeholder="TOTAL DEBIT"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
      <input
        id="DEBIT"
        class="form-control rounded-0 sum"
        disabled
        placeholder="0.00"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pr-0">
      <input
        class="form-control total rounded-0"
        disabled
        placeholder="TOTAL CASHLESS"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
      <input
        id="CASHLESS"
        class="form-control rounded-0 sum"
        disabled
        placeholder="0.00"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `And this is what I've done` - what was the problem with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Issue is that after you clone a node in JavaScript its event listeners are not copied from the source element.

In your case all the input fields where you assigned the `onChange` `handleSelectChange` event have lost those event listeners in the cloned node.

All you have to do is reassign those `onChange` event on the cloned nodes element.

```js
// extend form
const btn = document.getElementById("add-button");
const formClone = document.querySelector(".clone");
const parentForm = document.querySelector(".wrappers");

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const clone = formClone.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((e) => {
    e.value = "";
  });
  
  clone.querySelector(".type-payment").addEventListener('change', handleSelectChange);
  clone.querySelector(".input-price").addEventListener('change', handleSelectChange);
  clone.querySelector(".input-pay").addEventListener('change', handleSelectChange);
  
  parentForm.appendChild(clone);

  const deleteForm = document.createElement("button");
  deleteForm.innerText = "X";
  deleteForm.classList.add("btn", "btn-danger", "btn-sm");
  clone.appendChild(deleteForm);

  deleteForm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  });
});


const allInputSum = document.querySelectorAll(".sum");


function handleSelectChange(event) {
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".clone");
  const totals = {'CASHLESS': 0, 'DEBIT': 0, 'CASH': 0};
  
  forms.forEach(form => {
      const payment = form.querySelector(".type-payment");
    const price = form.querySelector(".input-price");
    const pay = form.querySelector(".input-pay");
    const inputTotal = form.querySelector(".input-total");
    let totalValue;

    totalValue = pay.value - price.value;
    inputTotal.value = totalValue.toLocaleString();
    totals[payment.value] += totalValue;
    })
  
  Array.from(allInputSum).filter((e) => {
    console.log([e.value, e.id, totals])
    e.value = totals[e.id] || 0;
  });

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="add-button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add Form</button>
<div class="wrappers">
  <div class="row clone mb-2">
    <div class="col px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control rounded-0 input-price"
          placeholder="Price"
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control rounded-0 input-pay"
          placeholder="Pay"
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <select
          class="form-control rounded-0 type-payment"
          role="button"
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
        >
          <option value="CASH">CASH</option>
          <option value="DEBIT">DEBIT</option>
          <option value="CASHLESS">CASHLESS</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col px-0">
      <div class="input-group mb-2">
        <input
          onchange="handleSelectChange(event)"
          value="0.00"
          type="text"
          class="form-control rounded-0 input-total"
          disabled
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pr-0">
      <input
        class="form-control total rounded-0"
        disabled
        placeholder="TOTAL CASH"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
      <input
        id="CASH"
        class="form-control rounded-0 sum"
        disabled
        placeholder="0.00"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pr-0">
      <input
        class="form-control total rounded-0"
        disabled
        placeholder="TOTAL DEBIT"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
      <input
        id="DEBIT"
        class="form-control rounded-0 sum"
        disabled
        placeholder="0.00"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 pr-0">
      <input
        class="form-control total rounded-0"
        disabled
        placeholder="TOTAL CASHLESS"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
      <input
        id="CASHLESS"
        class="form-control rounded-0 sum"
        disabled
        placeholder="0.00"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Try this code, I have made the required changes you need.

Comment: How to do that? @DipoAhmed

Comment: @Tom-Cat Try the changed code.

Comment: Thanks, it work @DipoAhmed . Can you explaine about your code?

Comment: @Tom-Cat There was couple of issues in your code.
 1. You didn't assign the event listeners on your copied node
 2.  You didn't calculate every input box in the form.

what i did was selected every row from  the form and made a for loop and the calculate  the amount for each row and set it to total. I am also saving that total in an object where your payment value is the key. All I am doing is running this operation  on every onChange event of input boxes.

Comment: ahh I see. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks @DipoAhmed